# Selectively disabling checked iterators

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2008, stl, iterator

I am writing a fairly complex application that makes heavy use of STL containers. The application has a single, relatively simple, performance sensitive section that iterates over multiple `std::map`s and is executed thousands of times. Testing has shown than compiling with checked iterators disabled (`_SECURE_SCL` set to 0) results in almost a 2x speedup of the program as a whole, entirely concentrated in this section.

However, I cannot compile the application with `_SECURE_SCL` set to 0 because need to link with libraries that were compiled with `_SECURE_SCL` enabled and mixing `_SECURE_SCL` settings leads to problems. Also, I find it rather silly to use unchecked iterators in the entire application, when all the performance sensitive bits happen in a single screenful of code. That would be tantamount to tossing out the baby with the bathwater.

What options do I have to selectively use unchecked iterators for performance sensitive code/containers while maintaining compatibility with libraries compiled with checked iterators?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help!

Comment: Glad to help. A good question should look good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
vector<BYTE> v;
vector<BYTE>::iterator i;
vector<BYTE>::iterator::_Unchecked_type ui;

i = v.end();
ui = i._Unchecked();

ui++;
```

Comment: It works great, you are my hero! It's amazing how hard it is to find information on these things.

Comment: This solution does not seem to be supported in VC9/VS2008, is this correct?

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'm not in the position to upgrade the entire build system to VS2010 right now, but at least I know it can be done.

Answer (score 6):

As you have already found out, you can't mix code that uses checked/unchecked iterators, so in order to use it in part of your code, you need to give that part an interface that does not require passing any containers and iterators. (Note that this extends to `std::string`.)
And of course you will have to put that code into its own executable (DLL). Of course, this requires that there aren't too many calls back and forth across that API.

To be on the safe side, I'd even consider putting that part into a DLL with a C interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's not quite what I hoped to hear, but it makes sense. What about using containers from a different STL implementation?